# Google Calendar API insert event without auth Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to insert events in my Calendar without user auth.

variables:

```
  OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
  APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Ruby Quickstart'
  CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = './lib/client_secret.json'
  CREDENTIALS_PATH = File.join(Dir.home, '.credentials',
                               "calendar-ruby-quickstart.yaml")
  SCOPE = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR

  def initialize(meeting_data)
   @meeting_data = meeting_data
  end
```

Authorize process:

```
  def authorize
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(CREDENTIALS_PATH))

    client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)
    token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: CREDENTIALS_PATH)
    authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(
        client_id, SCOPE, token_store)
    user_id = '2'
    credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
    if credentials.nil?
      url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(
          base_url: OOB_URI)
      puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " +
               "resulting code after authorization"
      puts url
      code = gets
      credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
          user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
    end
    credentials
  end
```

Creating method:

```
def create_meeting
    # Initialize the API
    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
    service.authorization = authorize
    ...
    # Create event end post
    ...
  end
```

When i start this methods, i must to make some console tricks(I take a token from google and past them into console) and after that event posting. Can I automate this process? Or take token which has long life time?

This process must work without user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Needed use server-to-server auth.

Next page has this solution: [Rails + Google Calendar API events not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766851/rails-google-calendar-api-events-not-created)