# Rails + Google Calendar API events not created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api

I created rails web app. When user make some actions, my app must create new event in my Google Calendar. For my task I choose server-to-server authorization.

I wrote next ruby code:

```
  client = Google::APIClient.new({:application_name => "Rails calendar",
                         :application_version => "1.0"})

  keypath = Rails.root.join('config','google_secrets.p12').to_s
  key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(keypath, "notasecret")

# generate request body for authorization
  client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
      :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
      :audience             => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
      :scope                => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
      :issuer               => '***',
      :signing_key          => key).tap{ |auth| auth.fetch_access_token! }


  api_method = client.discovered_api('calendar','v3').events.insert
  @meeting_data = {
      guests: [{email: '***@gmail.com'}, {email: '***@gmail.com'}],
      start_time: "2016-08-10T19:00:00+03:00",
      end_time: "2016-08-10T20:00:00+03:00",
      topic: "Test meeting",
      messages_thread_id: 2
  }

  event = {
      summary: @meeting_data[:topic],
      start: {
          dateTime: @meeting_data[:start_time],
          time_zone: 'Asia/Jerusalem'
      },
      end: {
          dateTime: @meeting_data[:end_time],
          time_zone: 'Asia/Jerusalem'
      },
      attendees: @meeting_data[:guests],
      visibility: 'private',
      reminders: {
          useDefault: true,
      }
  }

  result = client.execute(:api_method => api_method,
                          :parameters => {calendarId: 'primary'},
                          :body => JSON.dump(event),
                          :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

  puts result.data.as_json
```

But when i try to use that code and server return me result as JSON, if I go on url of "created" event, google show me message that event does not exist.

```
{"kind"=>"calendar#event", "etag"=>"***", "id"=>"***", "status"=>"confirmed", "htmlLink"=>"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=***", "created"=>"2016-08-04T11:54:46.000Z", "updated"=>"2016-08-04T11:54:46.327Z", "summary"=>"Test meeting", "creator"=>{"email"=>"***", "self"=>true}, "organizer"=>{"email"=>"***", "self"=>true}, "start"=>{"dateTime"=>"2016-08-10T16:00:00Z", "timeZone"=>"Asia/Jerusalem"}, "end"=>{"dateTime"=>"2016-08-10T17:00:00Z", "timeZone"=>"Asia/Jerusalem"}, "visibility"=>"private", "iCalUID"=>"***", "sequence"=>0, "attendees"=>[{"email"=>"***@gmail.com", "displayName"=>"***", "responseStatus"=>"needsAction"}, {"email"=>"***@gmail.com", "displayName"=>"***", "responseStatus"=>"needsAction"}], "reminders"=>{"useDefault"=>true}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced with same problem. Needed give write rules to "client_email" for calendar.

You use organization calendar. Thats why only organization admin can do it.